# Requested texture dimension exceeds maximum texture size

Tags: javafx-8

In JavaFx, I have a program in which the renderthread sometimes crashes with a message that the requested texture dimension is too large. If I read the stacktrace correctly I guess it happens in an NGCanvas (which probably stands for native graphics canvas, the implementation side of the JavaFx Canvas node).

I checked the sizes of the canvases I allocate and none come close to this size. Now, because JavaFx runs its rendering in its own thread, I don't even know who created this.

Is there any way I can find out who tells the renderpipeline to allocate such large texture ?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested texture dimension (65824) requires dimension (0) that exceeds maximum texture size (16384)
    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2RTTexture.getCompatibleDimension(ES2RTTexture.java:135)
    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2ResourceFactory.getRTTWidth(ES2ResourceFactory.java:146)
    at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSDrawable.getCompatibleWidth(PPSDrawable.java:48)
    at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSRenderer.getCompatibleWidth(PPSRenderer.java:153)
    at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.ImagePool.checkOut(ImagePool.java:119)
    at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.Renderer.getCompatibleImage(Renderer.java:116)
    at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSRenderer.getCompatibleImage(PPSRenderer.java:168)
    at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSRenderer.getCompatibleImage(PPSRenderer.java:67)
    at com.sun.scenario.effect.Effect.getCompatibleImage(Effect.java:479)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas$RenderInput.filter(NGCanvas.java:1582)
    at com.sun.scenario.effect.FilterEffect.filter(FilterEffect.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.applyEffectOnAintoC(NGCanvas.java:737)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.renderStream(NGCanvas.java:1080)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.renderContent(NGCanvas.java:606)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:576)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:477)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:330)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

As per request: the environment I use is linux debian amd64, jdk 1.8 update 66. The rendering happens through mesa.

Comment: Can you add details about you environment? I am sure I had seen this issue reported in the openjdk bugs.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha added more info on environment.

Comment: I am not sure of you are falling to the same problem but you might want to check - [Exception when filling shape with ImagePattern based on large image](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089876)

Comment: Does not seem to be related to this problem.

Comment: Could it be a bug in the driver? Try running your program with `-Dprism.order=sw` to force software rendering. If it helps, you may want to try and update your GPU driver (and at any rate posting your current version and graphic configuration may be relevant).

Comment: No bug in the driver. It also happens under windows 7; which I suspect are completely different drivers.

Comment: Did you try the software, `sw`, suggestion? Did it work or fail?  Can you provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to readily reproduce the issue?  Why are you trying to work with such large textures?  Maximum texture size can be a limitation of the underlying graphics hardware, not necessarily the driver.  You may need to work with nodes that have smaller dimensions. For example, the maximum texture size supported by the underlying graphics hardware may range from 4096x4096 to 16384x16384 depending on the chip.

Comment: I encountered the same exception. In my case, the culprit is clearly a VBox that is too large, so "canvas" is a bit misleading.  Looks if you get this exception, you need to check all Nodes in your program to see if they are too large, even if (as in my case) they are scrolled off-screen in a scroll pane.

Comment: Addendum: it wasn't just having the large VBox, but having one and trying to apply a clip and perspective-transform effect to it, which I think in turn required JavaFX to create an image of the node. The large VBox by itself is fine, it was my custom animation which was causing the exception.

Answer (score -1):

In javaFx only the javaFx application thread is allowed to modify the canvas.
Try using Platform.runLater() to pack your draw call onto the graphicsContext into a new Runnable.

Comment: I know that. JavaFx will even complain if you dare to use the wrong thread. But that has nothing to do with the question.